# Transfer Angular 2 Source Code

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, angular2-build

I developed an app with Angular 2 and I want to send it to the employer for code review.

Is it okay if I just copy and files and folders? If yes which files and folders I should copy?

If no, how can I build my application and send it to my employer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using System.js to transpile your typescript code in browser directly then you can go ahead and send it to them.

But if you are using angular-cli using npm then you need to provide instructions of npm angular-cli installation.

Comment: Thank you so much Tej, I'm using angular-cli using npm. Do you where I can get more info (step by step) or examples about how to do it?

Comment: Do you think should I use ng build --prod or --dev?

Comment: You can use ng build --dev. I think only difference this makes is the rate of refresh of the app page to detect any changes.